# Does adding a canonical URL affect underlying (subdirectory) URLs?

Tags: seo, url, rel-canonical, subdirectory

I am uncertain about a certain change. We have the following structure.

- Domain: ranks for keyword X
- `/main-category` (has strong relation to domain name itself and possibly cannibalizes the man domain ranking)
- `/main-category/some-example`

In the past we had a canonical tag on the URI `/main-category` pointing to `/` (Domain). Somehow this was removed.

Now I want to add the canonical tag again on `/main-category` pointing to `/`. Why? Because the pages are almost identical & also main-category does not rank at all - the Domain does for the given keyword.

My only worry is: What happens to the ranking of a page `/main-category/some-example` that is a child of `/main-category`?  Should I worry about this? (I can imagine it is rather strange to Google that some parent element in a tree hierarchy has a canonical tag on it and the children do not.)

Answer (score 2):

You're not applying the canonical link to the directory, but on the page that is served when someone visits that URI. Canonical links are specific to individual pages, so applying one to the directory's index would have no impact on other pages within it.